# How do I bring in Double values from one ActionListener method into another to perform a calculation? Java

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm creating a JFrame program of a basic Quadratic Formula calculator. I've created an Action listener to turn three text fields into three Double values, equal to a, b and c, which are used within the Quadratic Formula. I can't figure out how to put these into my other ActionListener for the button when the user finishes. The buttons purpose is to perform the calculation of the Quadratic Equation once the user has finished and display the answer on a new JFrame. Here is my code, anyone have suggestions for how to go about doing this?

Edit: I'm getting an error when trying to perform the calculations telling me "can't find symbol"

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.math.*;


public class GUISource extends JFrame {

private JTextField textA;
private JTextField textB;
private JTextField textC;
private JLabel labA;
private JLabel labB;
private JLabel labC;
private JButton butA;
private JButton butB;
private JButton butC;

public GUISource(){


    super ("Quadratic Equatic");
    setLayout (new FlowLayout());

    labA = new JLabel("Enter your A value:");

    add(labA);

    textA = new JTextField(30);

    add(textA);

    butA = new JButton("Enter");

    //add(butA);

    labB = new JLabel("Enter your B value:");

    add(labB);

    textB = new JTextField(30);

    add(textB);

    //butB = new JButton("Enter");

    //add(butB);

    labC = new JLabel("Enter your C value:");

    add(labC);

    textC = new JTextField(30);

    add(textC);

    //butC = new JButton("Enter");

    //add(butC);

    add(butA);



    listenPlease handle = new listenPlease();
    //labA.addActionListener(handle);
    //labB.addActionListener(handle);
    //labC.addActionListener(handle);
    //butA.addActionListener(handle);
    //butB.addActionListener(handle);
    //butC.addActionListener(handle);
    textA.addActionListener(handle);
    textB.addActionListener(handle);
    textC.addActionListener(handle);

    buttonListen handler = new buttonListen();

    butA.addActionListener(handler);



}


private class listenPlease implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){

        String transfer = "";

        if (e.getSource() == textA){
            transfer = String.format("field 1 : %s", e.getActionCommand());
            double a = Integer.parseInt(transfer);

        }
        else if(e.getSource() == textB){
            transfer = String.format("field 2: %s", e.getActionCommand());
            double b = Integer.parseInt(transfer);

        }
        else if(e.getSource() == textC){
            transfer = String.format("frield 3: %s", e.getActionCommand());
            double c = Integer.parseInt(transfer);

        }

    }


}

private class buttonListen implements ActionListener{

    //private double a;
    //private double b;
    //private double c;


    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ButtonPress){


        JFrame Answer = new JFrame("Answer");

        Answer.setSize(200, 200);

        double d = (Math.pow(b, 2)+(4 * a * c));



    }


}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the three `double`s in static variables:

```
public class GUISource extends JFrame {
//same as before
    private JTextField textA;
    private JTextField textB;
    private JTextField textC;
    private JLabel labA;
    private JLabel labB;
    private JLabel labC;
    private JButton butA;
    private JButton butB;
    private JButton butC;

    public static double a =0,b=0,c=0;
```

and then in your actionListener:

```
if (e.getSource() == textA){
   transfer = String.format("field 1 : %s", e.getActionCommand());
   double a = Integer.parseInt(transfer);
   GUISource.a = a;
}
//similarly for b and c
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! This fixed it! Much appreciated!

Comment: @bordia then you should accept the answer and upvote it if you find it useful

Comment: I will when the 10 minute delay for accepting answers allows me!

Comment: @bordia I see... didn't know it existed

Comment: Yeah I didn't either... Until 2 minutes ago.